# d3.csv doesnt load numeric matrix

Tags: javascript, csv, d3.js

I want to load an external .csv file using d3.csv.

This is data.csv (created in vim):

```
x,y
2,2
99,18
```

This is the d3 code:

```
d3.csv("data.csv", function(dataset){
console.log(d3.max(dataset, function(d){return d["y"];})); 
});
```

Even though I expected '18' the output in the console I get is '2'. If I change the '18' to another number, e.g. '35' the output is correct again. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The numbers are interpreted as strings, you need to convert them to numbers. Try `+d["y"]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These numbers are getting loaded as Strings, and that's causing unexpected behavior of d3.max. You need to cast the values into Numbers.

You can turn them into numbers via `Number(d.y)` or (`parseInt`, `parseFloat`). In d3 you often see it shortened as `y: +d.y`.

With `d3.csv` you can specify a function where you can do this conversion as it parses. [See documentation](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/CSV).

Comment: thank you, I followed the example in the documentation under 'parse'. Everything works as intended now. Do you know why the problem only occured with certain numbers (like 10,11,12,100, ...) and not with others (like 23, 35, ...) ?

Comment: I'd have to check the source code of d3.max to be sure, but most likely it's using greater than or less than operators internally. In that case the string "2" is greater than "18", because string compare works essentially like alphabetical sorting and the latter starts with "1", which comes before "2".